# How to prevent setinterval from ending when phone Hold(turn off the screen)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a web app by turning it into a PWA with REACT. However, our core technology is to print a map by receiving geolocation with setinterval, but setinterval is not performed when the phone is Hold (screen is turned off).

Any solution?

In addition, I ask if there is a way to do it for iOS as well.

Comment: "print a map" ... do you mean "display a map" ... in that case, why do you need to display a map on a screen that is turned off? simply wait for the screen to "turn on" and display your map

Comment: It not only displays the map, but also shows the route according to the current location in real time.

Comment: Oh, well, then that's a problem - does `requestAnimationFrame` work when the screen is off? or maybe `setTimeout` in a `worker`